# Magento2: Object DOMDocument should be created

Tags: magento2, template, compare

I have installed the Tigren_Ajaxcompare extension. Got the error message below

**Object DOMDocument should be created**.

**Block**

```
<?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2017 www.tigren.com
 */

namespace Tigren\Ajaxcompare\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Tigren\Ajaxcompare\Helper\Data;

class Js extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_template = 'js/main.phtml';

    protected $_ajaxCompareHelper;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $ajaxCompareHelper,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_ajaxCompareHelper = $ajaxCompareHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getAjaxCompareInitOptions()
    {
        return $this->_ajaxCompareHelper->getAjaxCompareInitOptions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like **generation** or **var** or **pub** folder is not writable. Verify that the following have writable permission by the web server:

- **`var`** folder
- **`pub/static`** folder
- **`generated`** folder
- **`app/etc`** folder

Another possible reason for this error is if your class folders don't have proper capitalization (i.e. are lowercase).

Please check **`system.log`** and **`exception.log`** for more clues.